# PostgreSQL - Incorrect time

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, proxy, timezone, dbeaver

I have a database that is deployed in GCP. I connect to DB via the GCP console and use Dbeaver to run queries. When I run SELECT NOW(); it's showing the time at which I started the session and not the current time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you started a TRANSACTION and NOW() shows you the time the transaction started. You have 2 option to solve this issue:

- Don't use a transaction and you can work with NOW()
- Or inside a transaction, use CLOCK_TIMESTAMP()

See also [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) about this behaviour.